# Stata loop breaks after 1st loop, how to fix

Tags: loops, import, foreach, stata

What am I doing wrong with this Stata code? After the first loop I got this error:

```
file file_XXX.dta saved
varlist required
r(100);
```

Here is the code:

```
import excel using "my_file.xlsx", describe
    forvalues sheet=1/`=r(N_worksheet)' { 
        local sheetname=r(worksheet_`sheet')  
        capture import excel using "my_file.xlsx", sheet("`sheetname'")  
        save "file_`sheetname'", replace
        ds, has(type string)
        local strvars "`r(varlist)'"  
        foreach var of varlist `strvars' {
            replace `var' = strtrim(`var')
            replace `var' = stritrim(`var')
            }
        save "file_`sheetname'", replace
        clear
        exit
    }
```

Comment: See advice at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing reproducible here, but you would run into a problem if there were no string variables `import`ed from a worksheet. `ds` would have no problem reporting an empty result, but your `foreach` loop would fail with the error message reported.